# Nginx not showing index.php

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

So guys i have runned a docker-compose who contain instructions to up a container with nginx another with php and another with mysql, but when i try to acess nginx he gives me this error:

**403 Forbidden**

I think that could be something wrong in his config, here his config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

For the case here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./code/public_html:/code
            - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        links:
            - php
    php:
        image: php7-custom-conf
        volumes:
            - ./code/public_html:/code
        links:
            - db
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
        - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbrootpass
         MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
         MYSQL_USER: dbuser
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpass
```

Any help is appreciated, anyway thanks for the attention.
Sorry for any errors not a english speaker here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is fine. But it looks like nginx can't access your code/public_html folder. Make sure it's executable for all users, e. g. `chmod 0755 ./code/public_html`. Another solution is to change the user and/or group of the nginx process to match the owner of the public_html folder.

Comment: You are saying of the folder mapped in the host(my machine) dont you? in this case that folder is inside Documents folder, i thought that is public for all users, but i'll give a try later, anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, mounted folders appear in containers with host permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `location ~ \.php$`.

Try replacing it with:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass http://php:9000;
}
```

---

I retest it. If you connect to http://localhost/ it'll return a 403 because the rights are wrong (thanks to @dizeee) but if you try to connect to http://localhost/index.php it returns a 404 because the proxy_pass is not defined.

Comment: Do i have to replace the whole block with that instruction or just adding on there will be ok?

Comment: Try first replacing, I noticed that there are other solutions. I might be wrong.

Comment: i'm at the work right now, when i go home i'll give a try(its a college project) thanks for the answer

Comment: Even when i not using nginx like a proxy, what made you think that config could solve, i've been curious about it can you exaplain please?

Comment: well, I assume you use your nginx to server your static files. I wrote a stupid php file and it works with this setup.